# How do I add modules to PYTHONPATH variable for zenmap in Kali Linux

Tags: nmap, environment-variables

I installed zenmap in my Kali Linux but when tried to run it, the terminal gave me the following error telling me to add modules to the PYTHONPATH variable.

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali/Downloads]
└─# zenmap                                                                                                                                                          
Could not import the zenmapGUI.App module: 'No module named gtk'.
I checked in these directories:
   /usr/bin
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/soupsieve-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/beautifulsoup4-4.9.1-py2-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/PySocks-1.7.1-py27-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/cffi-wheels/setuptools-44.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/share/cffi-wheels/py-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   /usr/lib/python2.7
   /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
   /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
If you installed Zenmap in another directory, you may have to add the 
modules directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
```